# ARCore Cloud Anchors TTL expiry extension

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore

Is there a possibility to extend the time to live (TTL) of a particular cloud anchor from 365 days to a custom expiry? or never expire?

**The expiry limitation is a make-or-break deal.**

Looking forward to a positive response on this.

Google Cloud Anchor
https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/cloud-anchors/quickstart

Tried increasing the expiry limit using the Management API, but it didn't work